# Simple way to fit large number of single factor logistic regression models in R - automatically

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I have a dataset with one binary target variable called “target” and many many factors “F1”, F2”… “F200”. I’m trying to come up with code to fit 200 single factor logistic regression models and return the model summaries. Here is what I have so far

```
single <- function(df, factor){
    s <- summary(glm(as.formula(paste('target ~ ', factor, sep='')), family=binomial, data=df));
return(s);
}
single(data, c("F1", "F2", "F2"));
```

but this gives me only a summary of the first model. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `lapply`. It will return a list of model summary objects.

```
lapply(c("F1", "F2", "F3"),
       function(x) summary(glm(df[["target"]] ~ df[[x]], family=binomial)))
```

Your codes does not work because you run `paste('target ~ ', c("F1", "F2", "F2"), sep='')` which results in `"target ~ F1" "target ~ F2" "target ~ F2"`. Converted to a formula, it returns `target ~ F1`.

**Update**

A solution which returns a matrix of regression results.

An example data frame:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(target = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE),
                 F1 = rnorm(10), F2 = rnorm(10), F3 = rnorm(10))


predictors <- c("F1", "F2", "F3")    
fits <- sapply(predictors,
               function(x) {
                 tmp <- try(coef(summary(glm(as.formula(paste("target", x, sep = "~")),
                                             family=binomial, data = df)))[2, ], TRUE)
                 if (class(tmp) == "try-error") NULL else tmp})
```

The result (`fits`):

```
                   F1         F2        F3
Estimate   -0.1864527 -1.2242511 0.6751601
Std. Error  0.8259677  1.0915999 0.8770035
z value    -0.2257384 -1.1215200 0.7698488
Pr(>|z|)    0.8214049  0.2620666 0.4413896
```

Comment: Brilliant. Is there an easy way to summarise results (from the list) into a data.frame so it is easier to see which factors are the strongest predictors? I accepted the solution BTW. This could only be an extra +

Comment: Also another minor thing. The summary(glm)) stuff is a little bit criptic as it shows something like "data[[x]]" instead real factor name F167 for example.

Comment: @user13467 See the update of my answer.

Comment: thanks. Your code works well, but when I run it against my real data half way through I'm getting the "subscript out of bounds" error. I presume this is happening because if model can not be fit there is no [2,] part to select from summary glm summary. I suppose I need to find a way to check if model was fit and THEN look up coefficients

Comment: @user13467 I added error handling. See update.

Comment: You are amazing. Never heard of this function....where did you dig it from... very useful indeed! Thanks a million.